# Why does "return" doesn't return anything (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

I wrote a code about finding the vowels in a word. I got my output thanks to console.log, it works. But once i try with return, it does not return anything.. I dont understand why?

Here the code :

```js
function vowelCount(str) {
  let word = str.split("");
  //   console.log(word);
  //   console.log(word.length - 1);
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= word.length - 1; i++) {
    if (
      str[i] === "a" ||
      str[i] === "e" ||
      str[i] === "i" ||
      str[i] === "o" ||
      str[i] === "u" ||
      str[i] === "y"
    ) {
      count = count + 1;
    }
  }
  //   console.log(count);
  return count;
}

vowelCount("hello");
vowelCount("thereactor");
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't return anything? You just call the function but don't do anything with the return value.

Comment: Assign the function return value to a variable const result = vowelCount("stackoverflow") . And use it how you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning. You are just not using the return value. This can be determined by:

```
console.log(vowelCount("hello"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the returned data.

`var vowelsInHello = vowelCount("hello");`

`console.log(vowelsInHello);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns a value. Maybe you didn't call the function. Note: call the function with a string, like: console.log("hello world");

Answer (score 0):

this is a slightly better way to do that

```
function vowelCount(str) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
        var char = str.charAt(i).toLowerCase()
        if (
            char === "a" ||
            char === "e" ||
            char === "i" ||
            char === "o" ||
            char === "u" ||
            char === "y"
        ) {
            count++
        }
    }
    return count;
}
console.log(vowelCount('this has some vowels'))
```